# "Error C3867: non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member" when using virtual stream manipulator

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

In my code in Visual Studio 2015 i have interface:

```
struct IStr
{
    virtual std::ostream& beginMessage() = 0;
    virtual std::ostream& endMessage(std::ostream&) = 0;
};
```

And i have a class that implements this interface, like this:

```
#include <sstream>

struct MyStr : public IStr
{
    std::stringstream m_stream;
    std::ostream& beginMessage() override { return m_stream; }
    std::ostream& endMessage(std::ostream& ss) override { return std::endl(ss); }
};
```

However, i am getting an error when trying to compile simple code:

```
IStr * pStr = new MyStr();
pStr->beginMessage() << "Hello Wordl!" << pStr->endMessage;
```

With message:

```
Error   C3867   
'IStr::endMessage': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

I really like syntax i am trying to use. But is this possible? Maybe the problem is that my manipulator is virtual, or non-static?

Comment: That `IStr::` prefixes look fishy. But apart from that, the error seems to be pointing you in the right direction -- it makes no sense to pass a member function reference/pointer to an `ostream`, since it has no way of knowing what instance to invoke that method on. [Try making it static](http://ideone.com/RPdiyu).

Comment: @Cameron It's typo when writing this question. Yes. Sad. Is there workaround to make non-static manipulator suitable for me maybe..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NVI, and have `endMessage()` return a (stateful) manipulator that calls the virtual function on the stream when streamed.

```
struct IStr
{
    // other stuff

    private: 
    virtual std::ostream& doBeginMessage() = 0;
    virtual std::ostream& doEndMessage(std::ostream&) = 0;

    struct EndManip{
        IStr* istr;
    };
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ss, EndManip em){
        return em.istr->doEndMessage(ss);
    }
    public:
    EndManip endMessage() { return {this}; }
    std::ostream& beginMessage() { return doBeginMessage(); }
};
```

With this you'd do `pStr->beginMessage() << "Hello World!" << pStr->endMessage();`.

Comment: Your solution is great and works like a charm, and not "dirty" for interface part as well!

Answer (score 1):

You have written:

```
IStr * pStr = new MyStr();
pStr->beginMessage() << "Hello Wordl!" << pStr->endMessage;
```

while you should have written something similar to:

```
IStr * pStr = new MyStr();
pStr->beginMessage() << "Hello Wordl!" << pStr->endMessage(*pStream);
```

The difference here is in the (), which results in doing the function call instead of trying to pass a pointer to the function (which is most likely not your intent).